# Use Arduino Uno as 5V Power Source for Sensors Connected to ESP32 Microcontrollers

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, power, esp32

I am using an ESP32 WROVER B based microcontroller, which has 3.3V and 5V outputs. Due to poor soldering of the header and attempted removal of the solder (permanently damaged PCB etching electrical contacts around the 5V pin), the 5V pin doesn't output any current, so only the 3.3V works (e.g. lights up a LED). Some of my modules require 5V to work properly (according to their specification) e.g. sensors. Can I provide a 5V power source from another component (e.g. arduino uno 5V output, USB to TTL converter 5V power output or USB power supply) for these or use a GPIO output (I believe these are 3.3 volts only) on the ESP32 device itself, perhaps with level shifting? The ESP32 is powered via USB and no issues there (serial monitor shows it boots up okay).

Comment: I would suggest soldering a wire to the 5V pin of the 3.3V regulator, but it sounds like your soldering skills are not up to such a task. Yes you can use power from anywhere you like - just remember to connect the grounds.

Comment: A level shifter doesn't magically convert 3.3V to 5V. It takes 3.3V logic signals, and uses a 5V power supply to amplify the signals to 5V. A 3.3V to 5V level shifter requires a 5V external power supply. Second, the GPIO lines on a 3.3V device like an ESP32 will be 3.3V, and **very low current**. Even if there was a 5V logic pin available, you should not try to use it for 5V power. You need some regulated 5V external power source. A USB power supply, another Arduino, discrete 5V power supply, etc.

Comment: Note that using an Arduino Uno as a 5V supply is a poor choice. it needs a 7-12VDC input to it's regulator, and then uses a fairly inefficient linear regulator to regulate that down to 5V. It would also sit their running but doing nothing. Buy a cheap 5V regulated power supply that runs from mains power and be done with it.

Comment: you have a development board with esp32 microcontroler. the board has power outputs, not the MCU